# On Submit, variable that is supposed to change doesn't? Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

What i am trying to do is when the input is the same as the variable name the user can not press the button '**change**' but when the input is different the user is allowed to press the button '**change**' and the value name will change but the problem is that the variable is not changing... Why?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="sendNameForm">
    <input id="name" type="text" value="John"/>
    <button id="sendNameBtn" type="submit" disabled>Change</button>
</form>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#sendNameForm').submit(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        dis_enableNameSend();
        alert("Success!");
        return false;
    });

    var name= $('#name').val();

    function dis_enableNameSend(){
        var newName = $('#name').val();
        if(newName==name){
            document.getElementById("sendNameBtn").disabled = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("sendNameBtn").disabled = false;
        }
    }

    $('#name').on('input', function() {
        dis_enableNameSend();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried your code, it works fine. Do you think the variable `name` is not changing?

Comment: `name` is a reserved word, with side-effects. rename it and try again.

Comment: also, remove `var` from `var name = $('#name').val();` to update the global instead of create a local

Comment: For example when i insert "Mark" and press Change the variable is supposed to change from "John" to "Mark" but that is not working because if it was when i have "Mark" written on the input i wouldn't be able to press "Change"

Comment: Thank you! The Problem was that i was creating a local variable... I totaly missed that... Thanks for Helping! :D And maybe changing the name variable is a good ideia since it might cause problems in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

form submit generally refresh your page by default that may be reason why you do not see change.
try preventing default behaviour

```
$('#sendNameForm').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
        var name = $('#name').val();
        dis_enableNameSend();
        alert("Success!");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Actually the problem was that i was creating a local variable... But thanks anyways! :D